# Extract string in brackets when there are other brackets embedded in quotes

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to extract this bracketed part from a string:

```
[list items='["one","two"]' ok="no" b="c"]
```

I am using the following `preg_match` call:

```
preg_match('~\[([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[ ]+([a-zA-Z0-9]+=[^\[]+)\]~s', $string,$match)
```

But I have trouble with the brackets that appear within quotes.

I have two files

#### theme.html

```
[list items=""one","[x]tw"'o"" ok="no" b="c""/]
@book
[button text="t'"extB1" name="ok"'" /]
    Asdfz " s wr aw3r '
[button text="t"'extB2" name="no"'" /]
```

#### file.php

```
$string=file_get_contents('theme.html');
for (;;) { 
    if (!preg_match('~\[([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[ ]+([a-zA-Z0-9]+=[^\[]+)\]~s', $string,$match)) {
        exit;
    }
    $string=str_replace($match[0], '', $string);
    echo "<pre><br>";
    print_r($match);
    echo "<br></pre>";
}
```

and this is output:

```
<pre><br>Array
(
    [0] = [button text="textB1" name="ok"]
    [1] = button
    [2] = text="textB1" name="ok"
)
<br></pre>
<pre><br>Array
(
    [0] = [button text="textB2" name="no"]
    [1] = button
    [2] = text="textB2" name="no"
)
<br></pre>
```

As you can see the output does not include

```
[list items='["one","two"]' ok="no" b="c"]
```

I know the problem is caused by the embedded square brackets, but I don't know how I can correct the code to ignore them.

Comment: Please provide input and output that actually relates to eachother. It seems the output you have provided does not correspond to the input at all.

Comment: @trincot thank you,  you're right!, edited!

Comment: I edited your question further to put the problem statement in the beginning and only then provide the further context of the two files. Hope it is OK for you.

Comment: @trincot THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this variation of your `preg_match` call:

```
if (!preg_match('~\[(\w+)\s+(\w+=(?:\'[^\']*\'|[^\[])+?)\]~s', $string, $match))
```

With `\'[^\']*\'` it detects the presence of a quote and will grab all characters until the next quote, without blocking on an opening bracket. Only if that cannot be matched, will it go for the part you had: `[^\[])+`. I added a `?` to that, to make it non-greedy, which makes sure it will not grab a closing `]`.

Note also that `[a-zA-Z_]` can be shortened to `\w`, and `[ ]` can be written as `\s` which will also allow other white-space, which I believe is OK.

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/599925).

#### Alternative: match complete lines only

If the quotes can appear anywhere without guarantee that closing brackets appear within quotes, then the above will not work.

Instead we could require that the match must span a complete line in the text:

```
if (!preg_match('~^\s*\[(\w+)\s+(\w+=.*?)\]\s*$~sm', $string, $match))
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/599957).

Comment: thank you , theme.html is none static file and may be diffrent , if exist bracket or single quotation in the theme this pattern doesnt work correctly(e.g [list items="
 ["one","tw'o"'] ok="n'o" b="c'""]
 @book
[button text="t'"extB1" name="ok"'"]
 Asdfz " s wr aw3r '
[button text="t"'extB2" name="no"'"]) please write the better pattern

Comment: You really have that kind of input? It really makes no sense because the opening double quote after `[list items=` closes 3 characters later: `items=" ["`. So the closing `]` is  *outside* that quote. So how could you define it does not close the pattern you want to match? What is the syntax of this text? You have documentation of that strange format? Without an exact definition of the syntax it is not possible to define a regular expression for it. It is an exact science that needs exact specs.

Comment: the input may be a phpcode! or everything   ,Not just a plain text for echo

Comment: this code is for a part of a template engine  and The users may want to use each entry

Comment: So by which logic you want to match? It is not clear how you will decide which closing bracket to match with. Does the match always match with a full line (until the newline character)? If so, that could help.

Comment: I added an alternative to my answer based on the assumption that a match must span a complete line.

Comment: i changed theme.html file and replace ] to /] now you can get content if that have brackets in values?(I think it is way more convenient)

Comment: Did you check the alternative I posted?

Comment: yes the match cant extract text when there is a [] in the theme

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. [This](https://eval.in/599957) seems to do what you asked for, no? Please explain.